# eof in python 3.0 even with correct syntax and correct poutput

Tags: python

I am using proper input statement and giving proper inputs to the code then also it is giving NZEC error.Please can anyone help  also using python 3

```
def fun():
    T=int(input())
    for i in range(T):
        H,P=map(int,input().split())
        while (H > P):
            H = H - P
            P = P / 2
            if (H == 0):
                print(1)
                break
            elif (P == 0):
                print(0)
                break
        if (H < P):
            print(1)

        # H = 0
        # P = 0

fun()
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Comment: And the test input and expected output

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "./prog.py", line 2, in fun
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Test case is 2 for T ,10 4 then 10 8 for H ,P respectively

Comment: can the error be liike due to time complecity of this probelm is nlogn and the question is asking of n^2????

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `H,P=map(int,input().split())` to `H,P=map(int,input().strip().split())`

Comment: no its giving compilation error and also contraints are 0<T<10^5   , 0<P<10^6  ,  0<P<10^5,can it be like its asking for O(N^2) and code in O(ologn)????

Comment: ya,On pycharm too but on codechef its giving this error